# Jquery XML parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have an XML like this

```
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>    
    <name> </name>
</resultGroups>
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>    
    <name> </name>
</resultGroups>
```

I have this code to select number of results inside each resultGroup

```
$('resultGroups', $(xml)).each(function() {
    count = $('results', this).length;
    arr[i] = count;
    i++;
});
```

What I want is to get the name from each resultGroup tag and store it in an array.
How can I do that inside the above code?

How can I select only the name tag of the first resultGroup only without .each function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your XML looks like this:

```
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>    
    <name>myname</name>
</resultGroups>
<resultGroups> 
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>
    <subGroups>
        <results> </results>
        <results> </results>
    </subGroups>    
    <name>othername</name>
</resultGroups>
```

Using this code:

```
var groups = {};
$('resultGroups', $(xml)).each(function() {
    var count = $('results', this).length;
    var name = $('name',this).text();
    groups[name] = count;
});
```

After that, groups will be a dictionary (object, hence the {}) like so:

```
{'myname': 2, 'othername': 4}
```

Which you can access by doing `groups.myname` or `groups['myname']`

To get only the name tags directly in resultGroups tag - I didn't see any other in the example code, so I didn't know there were more - use this code instead:

```
var name = $(this).children('name').text();
```

Comment: since i dont the names...i used this code instead...two different arrays for count and names....

$('resultGroups', $(xml)).each(function() {
  
  var count = $('results', this).length;
  var name = $('name',this).text();
  resultGroupNames[i] = name;
  resultsNo[i] = count;
  i++;
 });

i got the counts correctly. but in case of names it stores all the names inside the resultGroup tags....ie names tags inisde subgroup results etc.. i want only the name tag directly inside resultGroup...